# Como fazer o tour Nas próximas vezes ficar sempre fechada

Tags: javascript, script

Visto que Ao carregar pela primeira vez, a caixa de informação onde está o botão para iniciar o Tour é exibida aberta logo após o carregamento da página, nas próximas vezes ela estará sempre fechada

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Dá pra gravar em `cookie` ou em `session`, depende. Cria uma forma que quando o usuário fazer o _Tour_ até o final (ou após visitar a página) que  grave uma informação e que essa informação seja interpretada até mesmo na não existência dela.